# I need help splitting an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, spreadsheet

I am having a difficult time editing this script.  It looks at one tab, pulls all rows that meet the criteria and pastes them into another tab.  The script below works, but doesn't quite fit my needs.  It is pasting the entire row, I only need Columns A,B and C.  Ideally, I would need the data copied into Columns A,D and E respectively. Thanks for any help!

```
    function Migrate2() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('OnBoard');
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NewHire');
    var val = sheet.getRange('a3:l').getValues();
    var headers = val.shift();
    var arr = [],
        rowsToWriteBack = [];

    rowsToWriteBack.push(headers);
    val.forEach(function (r, i) {
        r[7] == 'COMPLETE'&& r[11] == 'N' ? arr.push(r) : rowsToWriteBack.push(r)});

    if (arr.length > 0) {
        targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);

    }
   }
```

Comment: Minor edit ---  Line 8 should read var arr = [ ],

Comment: You can edit the code in the question by clicking "Edit" right below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Migrate2() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('OnBoard');
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NewHire');
    var val = sheet.getRange('a3:l').getValues();
    var headers = val.shift();
    var arr = [],
    rowsToWriteBack = [];

    rowsToWriteBack.push(headers);

    val.forEach(function (r, i) {
            r[7] == 'COMPLETE'&& r[11] == 'N' ? 
                arr.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]]) : 
                rowsToWriteBack.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]])
    });

        if (arr.length > 0) {
                            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + i + 1, 1, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][0]);
                                targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + i + 1, 4, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][1]);
                                targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + i + 1, 5, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][2]);
                            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hard to test without access to the environment you're working in, but I think the above should work. Good luck!

Here's the updated version that (hopefully) fixes the staggering issue:

```
function Migrate2() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('OnBoard');
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NewHire');
    var val = sheet.getRange('a3:l').getValues();
    var headers = val.shift();
    var arr = [],
    rowsToWriteBack = [];

    rowsToWriteBack.push(headers);

    val.forEach(function (r, i) {
            r[7] == 'COMPLETE'&& r[11] == 'N' ? 
            arr.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]]) : 
            rowsToWriteBack.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]])
    });

        if (arr.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var addToRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + i + 1;

                targetSheet.getRange(addToRow, 1, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][0]);
                targetSheet.getRange(addToRow, 4, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][1]);
                targetSheet.getRange(addToRow, 5, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

attempt #3 to prevent the row skipping

```
    function Migrate2() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('OnBoard');
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NewHire');
            var startingRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        var val = sheet.getRange('a3:l').getValues();
        var headers = val.shift();
        var arr = [],
        rowsToWriteBack = [];

        rowsToWriteBack.push(headers);

        val.forEach(function (r, i) {
                r[7] == 'COMPLETE'&& r[11] == 'N' ? 
                arr.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]]) : 
                rowsToWriteBack.push([r[0],r[1],r[2]])
        });

            if (arr.length > 0) {
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    var addToRow = startingRow + i;

                    targetSheet.getRange(addToRow, 1, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][0]);
                    targetSheet.getRange(addToRow, 4, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][1]);
                    targetSheet.getRange(addToRow, 5, 1, 1).setValues(arr[i][2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Kris!  That gets the data in the right columns.  But it is not putting them in the same row.  They are getting staggered.  I tried making adjustments to the "+1" and "+i", but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot as to what you mean by staggered?

Comment: I think I see the problem, one sec

Comment: I removed the + i and +1 from the last 2 lines.  And everything landed on the same row.  But it is skipping a row between the data.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!   I have been working on this issue for 4 days!!!   Any idea why it is skipping a row inbetween?

Comment: I believe it's because of the `getLastRow` method call, I put another edit in my answer that will hopefully fix the issue :)

Comment: SUCCESS!!!!  I cannot thank you enough!!!  I did have to make the minor edit of changing setValues to setValue